What is meant in the recent blogpost by "flagging out of date content"?
The recent blogpost says:

We’re also exploring ways in which AI and ML can [...] reduce the burden of work on our mods and curators by assisting in content review and flagging out of date content

Note that the context for that quote is from a section talking about the "global community" and public platform- not SO for Teams.
Concerns aside about what that means with AI being involved in content review and flagging,

What does it mean to "flag out of date content"? There's no "out of date" flag reason as far as I know, or review queue for "out of date content". I know mods can put notices on top of posts with certain messages about content issues. Is this referring to that?
What definition/meaning of "out of date" is being used here?
What will be done with this "out of date" information?


I assumed "flag" was meant in the colloquial sense of "identify and keep track of".

@KarlKnechtel: I think your interpretation is correct.

If only the owners of the site understood the site and what keywords there are, if that's the case @KarlKnechtel . Then they could ensure they don't use ambiguous language.

Nah. They'd use it anyway just to keep us on our toes.

When there's so much jargon, it's hard to avoid bumping into it.

Normally I'd agree with that, but this just feels excessive - both because flagging is a pretty basic feature of SE and because "track" is a better word here than "flag" anyways.

@Barmar 'flag' isn't jargon, it's a first class action that people do thousands of times a day across the network, that has been around for... like 15 years? That's like saying they can be forgiven for not being familiar with the fact that questions can be closed. That argument doesn't pass the smell test when it's your product you're talking about.

"What definition/meaning of "out of date" is being used here?" - Yes, that one makes me nervous. I hope it has to do with abandonment and not so much age.

@TylerH What I mean is the specific way it's used in SE is company jargon, while there's also the general term that's used in the sentence under discussion.

Yeah now we're just looking reasons to be petty. Words have different meanings, context matters. It is established meta lore that the blog is very far removed from the actual site.

@Gimby I'm not trying to be petty. I mean, I often can be, but right now I'm genuinely curious what this statement is supposed to mean. I don't understand it at all and I want to.

@Barmar Honestly, the language SEI employees use is some odd North American corporate/marketing lingo, mostly detached from the language people on the sites use. Sometimes in the mist you glimpse a familiar looking word, but from the surrounding context it quickly becomes evident that the meaning is completely different. (Like "community" to name an example) And the rift just seems to be growing.

If I read the blog I don't think I would have given this a second thought. "flagging out of date content" seems obviously unrelated to the flags that users submit to moderators.
